# How to disable NetworkManager on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: network-manager

I already tried:

1. Commenting out `exec NetworkManager` in `/etc/init/network-manager.conf`.
2. `echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override`

However, `ps aux | grep NetworkManager` always shows that it is running after doing the above and rebooting.

Is my only option here to uninstall NetworkManager?

Comment: What exactly is the output of `ps aux | grep NetworkManager`?

Comment: `root@odroid:/var/log# ps aux | grep NetworkManager
root       971  0.0  0.3  73164  7188 ?        Ssl  22:46   0:00 ``/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
root      3503  0.0  0.0   3640   748 pts/0    S+   23:00   0:00 grep --color=auto NetworkManager`

Comment: It's unfortunate that the only way to disable it is to completely remove it ...

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug report with information on disabling it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/82335 Post #19

Could you uninstall NetworkManager and use `apt-get download network-manager` to download only? (In case you need it later, you could install while offline) This would download to the current directory, so you may want to move it.

Also, what problem are you having that you need to disable it?